# Javascript Array count doesn't agree with console?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Am I being stupid here? (I'm coming from Ruby, so there might be something about Javascript arrays that I'm missing).

`console.log(new_devices)`

Result in console: `Array[1]`.

`console.log(new_devices.length)`

Result in console: `0`

The code producing this:

```
var sp = require('serialport');
var new_devices = [];

sp.list(function(err, ports) {
  ports.forEach(function(current) {
    if (current.manufacturer == "Teensyduino") {
      new_devices.push(current);
    }
  });
});

console.log(new_devices);
console.log(new_devices.length);
```

[image]

Comment: You need to post the code that reproduces the issue. So far nobody can reproduce this. What does the `i` button next to the array say? Is something asynchronous going on?

Comment: Please Post The Code Using StackSnippet

Comment: No, nothing asynchronous.

Comment: Well I think it's pretty obvious that the desired behaviour is that the length printed to the console should agree with what Chrome thinks the length of the array is. Code added.

Comment: The code that populates `new_devices` sure looks asynchronous to me.

Comment: What happens if you put the `sp....` lines in comments?

Comment: Well that's confusing. Nothing about that looks asynchronous to me, but then I'm coming from Ruby and C...

Comment: @Alfo `sp.list` *is* asynchronous. Doesn't the docs state that?

Answer (score 2):

When you console log arrays the console creates a reference to that array, it does not show you a snapshot of the state of the array at the point of execution.

(In your code items are appended to the list async, so when the console log is printing the list is empty.)

Consider this example:

[image]

Comment: So how do I restructure this code in this so that I can get a correct number when I print `new_devices.length` to the console?

Comment: Move you console.log to after you ports.forEach